# Flipping two UIView using CATransform3D

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I have created Visiting Card which has Front view & back View. When i tap on the front view it should flip the UIView & show the back side of the View.

Here is Code which I am trying:

```
 CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1, 0);
 transform.m34 = 1.0/700.0;


 CABasicAnimation *rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
 rotation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
 rotation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];
 rotation.duration = DURATION;

 CABasicAnimation *translation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
 translation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(self.imageview.center.x,[[self.imageview superview] center].y-45)];
 translation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(_frame.origin.x+_frame.size.width/2,
                                                             _frame.origin.y+_frame.size.height/2)];
 translation.duration = DURATION;


 CABasicAnimation *translation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
 translation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(self.imageview.center.x,[[self.imageview superview] center].y-45)];
 translation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(_frame.origin.x+_frame.size.width/2,
                                                             _frame.origin.y+_frame.size.height/2)];
 translation.duration = DURATION;
 CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];

 group.animations = @[ translation, rotation ];
 group.duration = DURATION;
 group.delegate = self;
 group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
 group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
 [layer addAnimation:group forKey:nil];
```

Above code works perfectly for single view. How to combine the 2nd view to get flipping from front & back effect.

[image]

Comment: Regarding `_frame.origin.x+_frame.size.width/2`: why not use `CGRectGetMidX(_frame)`?

Answer (score 3):

## Using Core Animation

You can add both front and back to a container view. The back view will have a 180 degree rotation around Y and the front will be just normal. Both layers will be single sided (by setting `layer.doubleSided = NO;`.

Then when you apply the rotation you would animate the rotation of the container view so that both front and back animate at the same time.

## UIView transitions

Or you could just use the built in flip animation

```
transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:
```

and pass either `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft` or `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight` for the option.

Comment: Ronnqvist Thanks for giving me hint. layer.doublesided method helped me lot.